# MongoDB bsoncxx crash parsing a json document with int64_t value

Tags: c#, c++, json, mongodb, bson

I'm generating a json document in C# using the Bson library function ToJson(). The document starts with:

{ "Key" : NumberLong("2053249000001086"), ...

I'm parsing this document in a C++ DLL using the bsoncxx drivers.
An exception is thrown by this line:
'''bsoncxx::from_json(TheJsonDocument).view()'''

with What = "Got parse error at "u", position 11: "SPECIAL_EXPECTED": could not parse JSON document"

In other words: the NumberLong() tag is not supported.
The workaround I currently use is to export a string, and to read it with atoll() in  the DLL.

Any better idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extended json you produced is invalid. The correct spelling is

```
{"$numberLong": <64-bit signed integer as a string>}
```

See https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst#conversion-table.

You need to fix the producing side to produce correct extended json.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why is the MongoDB.Bson .net driver not generating the correct output? 
I expected at least that the document generated by the Bson driver in C# is compatible with the parser of the C++ Bson driver.

Comment: Which documentation are you following?